# Managing duplicate chunk of code in HTML

Tags: html, dom

I'm working on a scenario where I need to apply some settings based on condition and if condition is false, Need to show same thing in a different way. Everything is working fine except it caused a lot duplicate code in all html files. Actually I'm working on cross-platform apps with angular5/Typescript + ionic/Cordova.

Consider following example:

```
<ion-slides pager [hidden]='!isMobileDevice'>
    <ion-slide>
        <div id="div1">some contents</div>
    </ion-slide>
    <ion-slide>
        <div id="div2">more contents</div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>

<div [hidden]='isMobileDevice'>
    <div id="div1">some contents</div>
    <div id="div2">more contents</div>
</div>
```

In above code, same chunk of code is being replicated on two place and as these div1 and div2 are complete pages so its a lot of code. Just wondering is there some workaround which I can use to avoid this duplication in my pages. Any help/Suggestion would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Please add relevant tags, this is not just a html-question. Also as that "html" (this is not pure html) is right now, it has duplicate ids and thus is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

A slightly clumsy way would be to use *iframe*. If you have PHP configured you can use *include*. There's also *JQuery* that'll do something similar.
Your two separate pages, **somecontents.html** and **morecontents.html**, can then be called in multiple places without the duplication.